# Writing trigger in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I am trying to write a trigger checking the value in column table comparing it
to a count of value from another column this work perfectly but my trigger
itself written with the same idea doesn't prompt when I expected it to do so
this is my test it works fine

```
declare @nombreMax int
declare @cours int
declare  @maxtu int

set @cours = 1
set @maxtu = (select max_etudiant from Cours where id = @cours)

select @nombreMax = count(*) 
from [dbo].[ETUDIANT] 
where ETU_COURS = @cours

if (@nombreMax > @maxtu) 
    print 'depassé de ' 
else 
    print 'ok'
```

but this doesn't work - what am I missing?

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[VerifNombreEtu]
ON [dbo].[ETUDIANT]
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    DECLARE @ETU_ID INT
    DECLARE @cours nvarchar(50)
    DECLARE @status INT
    DECLARE @nombreEtu INT
    DECLARE @Max INT

    DECLARE Maxc2 cursor fast_forward for
         SELECT inserted.ETU_COURS 
         FROM Inserted

    OPEN Maxc2

    FETCH NEXT FROM Maxc2 INTO @ETU_ID

    SET @status = @@FETCH_STATUS

    WHILE @status = 0
    BEGIN
        SET @Max = (SELECT max_etudiant FROM Cours WHERE id = @cours)

        SELECT @nombreEtu = COUNT(*) 
        FROM [dbo].[ETUDIANT] 
        WHERE ETU_COURS = @cours

        IF(@nombreEtu > @Max)
        BEGIN
            RAISERROR('max students reached',17,1)
            ROLLBACK;
        END

        FETCH NEXT FROM Maxc2 INTO @ETU_ID

        SET @status = @@FETCH_STATUS
    END

    CLOSE Maxc2;
    DEALLOCATE Maxc2;
END
```

Comment: Side note: you should generally try to avoid cursors in T-SQL - and ***especially*** so in triggers. A trigger should be *very fast, small, nimble* and execute very quickly - a cursor is anything but any of these...... you should seriously put some effort into **elminating that cursor** inside your trigger to avoid performance penalties in your app ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause could be, that the variable **@cours** is not assigned a value in the trigger.

Comment: fetch next fROm Maxc2 into @cours and no into ETU_ID